# Extracting a base domain/eTLD+1 from a URL

Tags: javascript, url, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm currently writing a WebExtension. In this extension, I need to deal with a bunch of URLs in JS and extract the base domain (aka eTLD+1).

So

- `www.cnn.com` => `cnn.com`
- `cnn.com` => `cnn.com`
- `www.world.cnn.com` => `cnn.com`
- `www.bbc.co.uk` => `bbc.co.uk`
- ...

As you can see from the examples, there is no simple technique to extract everything. In fact, the [the official list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) is ~12,000 lines long.

I know that browsers can do it internally. I wonder if there is a standard way to do this in JS?

Comment: Maybe that helps you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Okay then I have an "manual" solotion that I will post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe too late but:

For browser usage, there is the [publicsuffixlist.js](https://github.com/gorhill/publicsuffixlist.js) implementation by Raymond Hill (uBlock origin author) that works well, and you can also optionally use WASM for better performance. You need also [punycode.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js).

simple usage (once you have publicsuffix.min.js and punycode.js) :

```js
// at this point you have the publicsuffix list in a string
const publicSuffixList = "must contain list from https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat";
window.publicSuffixList.parse(publicSuffixList, punycode.toASCII);

// optionnal enable wasm : need that you serve the WASM file with MIME type 
// "Content-Type: application/wasm"
window.publicSuffixList.enableWASM().then(status => {
   console.log("WASM status: ", status);
});

const host = "www.bbc.co.uk";
const hostPuny = punycode.toASCII(host);
const domain = window.publicSuffixList.getDomain(hostPuny);
console.log("eTLD+1 : ", punycode.toUnicode(domain));
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any JavaScript API but the following Node module looks like it does the trick: https://www.npmjs.com/package/publicsuffixlist

Answer (score -1):

This function works by using the cookie facility.

```
      function eTLDplus1() {
        let hostname = new URL(window.location.href).hostname;
        let parts = hostname.split('.');
        for( var i=parts.length-2; i>0; i--) {
          let test = parts.slice(i).join('.');
          document.cookie = "eTLDplus1test="+test+"; domain=."+test;
          let jar = parseCookies();
          if( jar['eTLDplus1test'] === test ) {
            document.cookie = "eTLDplus1test=; domain=."+test + "; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
            return test;
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: That code looks broken.